# package issue when using spring-data-commons with spring-boot-2.1.x

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-commons, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

I am working on Spring Boot migration from 1.5.12 to 2.1.14. We are using Gradle as a build tool, so as part of Spring Boot migration we had to change
Gradle from 3.x to 4.x and trying to update the build.gradle as required. After migrating, erros are showing in CRUDRepository related API's.

We are using spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and spring-data-commons

Before Migration:

1. spring-boot-starter-data-jpa - 1.5.12(getting it from  Spring boot
   version)
2. spring-data-commons (1.13.12.RELEASE)

No error in showing for org.springframework.data.repository package

After Migration:

1. spring-boot-starter-data-jpa - 2.1.14(getting it from  Spring boot
   version)
2. spring-data-commons (2.0.7.RELEASE)

Error: org.springframework.data.repository. not resolved

If I use spring-data-common-1.13.12.RELEASE with spring-boot-2.x, gets the below error.

reason: class file for org.springframework.data.repository.config.BootstrapMode not found

Can Some one suggest some thing to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Spring Boot `2.1.14.RELEASE` uses spring-data-commons `2.1.17.RELEASE` by default.

Comment: I have used spring-data-comoons and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa when my app was inn spring-boot 1.x, So Do we need to remove spring-data-coomons now?